# exporting data frame as a tsv-file (R)

Tags: r, export-to-csv

```
write_tsv("BL",path = "/Users/kmein/Desktop/project/results/BL.tsv",na = NA,append = T,col_names = T,quote_escape = double)
```

I want to export the R data frame BL as a tsv file to my project directory. Unfortunately the above code is not working. It shows an Error that data.frame is not TRUE

When I type in is.data:frame(BL) it shows TRUE. I do not know why the Error says otherwise.
What is wrong here? Any suggestions?
Thank you!

Comment: ```Error in write_delim(x, path, delim = "\t", na = na, append = append, : is.data.frame(x) is not TRUE``` That is the Error, if that helps

Comment: is it supposed to be BL? "BL" is a character, not a data.frame

Comment: actually, BL is the name of the data.frame

Comment: yes.. you need to do write.table(BL,path=..)

Comment: ```write_tsv(BL,path = "/Users/kmein/Desktop/project/results/BL.tsv",na = NA,append = T,col_names = T,quote_escape = double)```   it is not working either. But I appreciate your suggestion. ```Error in as.character(x) : cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'```that is a new Error. So something has changed. I think that is a good sign

Comment: what's the error then? I mean you can also do write.table(BL,"/Users/kmein/Desktop/project/results/BL.tsv",quote=FALSE,sep="\t")

Comment: Ok your error with write_csv comes from quote_escape = double and na=NA options. You need to provide a string. For example, quote_escape="double" and na="NA"

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am sometimes confused when I should use quotion marks and when I should not. I think I will understand it in the matter of time.